# running json-server in docker container

Tags: docker, json-server

I am trying to use docker-json-server from [json-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/williamyeh/json-server/)

It commands works fine on linux

```
docker run  \
  -p 3000:3000  -v `pwd`:/data  \
  williamyeh/json-server        \
  --watch db.json
```

But if I try this on windows

```
docker run williamyeh/json-server -p 3000:3000  -v e:\json-server --watch db.json
```

This does not work **unknown flag: --watch**. Please help how can I run this on windows-10, my db.json is in e:\json-server

Thanks

Comment: You've changed the command line to something completely wrong, whats the `e:\json-server` supposed to do and where is the image-name?

Comment: I added image name, e:\json-server is where my db.json exists. I am very new to docker on windows

Answer (score 0):

In your Windows version of the command, you've completely changed the order of the arguments, hence the error.

Based on your example, this is probably closer to what you're looking for.

`docker container run -p 3000:3000 -v e:\json-server:c:\data williamyeh/json-server --watch db.json`

Comment: The source path "E:/json-server:c" doesn't exist and is not known to Docker.